# How to set JestJS global timeout in package.json

Tags: jestjs

I am wondering how would I set up a global timeout for all my JestJS tests within package.json?

The default 5000ms is not sufficient for my tests. I don't want to be doing the following code for each of my tests:

```
it('should return foo', () => { .. }, timeout);
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can add `testTimeout` to your jest configuration

**`package.json`**

```
"jest": {
  "testTimeout": 10000,
}
```

or as a CLI option

**`package.json`**

```
"scripts": {
  "test": "jest --testTimeout=10000"
}
```

---

#### If you get the following warning

> ● Validation Warning:
>
> Unknown option "testTimeout" with value 10000 was found.
>    This is probably a typing mistake. Fixing it will remove this message.

you should upgrade jest

Comment: make sure to restart test when package.json was modified as it wont take effect

Comment: if you have jest already running with --watchAll flag it should reload after package.json was modified